# /var/log/messages sdb error messages. HP MSA50

Tags: debian, storage, hp, logging

I have a HP machine running Debian squeeze/sid. In the /var/log/messages log file, I have the following errors...

As well, when doing intense file transfer. Let's say... at backup time... After a while, the server crash.... This happens every day during the last minutes of doing the backup....

Any clues on what it can be ?

```
Aug 13 09:26:27 evil_server kernel: [4153896.705800] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
Aug 13 09:26:27 evil_server kernel: [4153896.738820] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] READ CAPACITY failed
Aug 13 09:26:27 evil_server kernel: [4153896.738824] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Aug 13 09:26:27 evil_server kernel: [4153896.738828] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
Aug 13 09:26:27 evil_server kernel: [4153896.738832] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Logical unit not ready, manual intervention required
```

Comment: What model controller are you using to interface with the MSA 50 enclosure? Can you provide the output of `df -h` and `fdisk -l`?

Comment: Here is the output pf fdisk -l. However, df -h would not five you much, only space of the partitions...

Comment: I asked so I could see how the drive is mounted. The answer to your issue depends heavily on which controller you're using and how the MSA 50 is configured.

Comment: Please try to reformat your question with the copy/paste output IN the question.

Answer (score 2):

Well, most of this is moot because the original question is a mess, but the StorageWorks MSA 50 is an HP device and looks to be accessed using an HP controller (probably a Smart Array P600 or P800 SAS RAID controller)...

This is denoted by the CCISS block device naming; `/dev/cciss/cXdYpZ`

In this case, your MSA 50's storage is presented at `/dev/cciss/c1d0p1`

Any issues you're having with `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sdb` means there's a problem with *those* devices. Your MSA 50 appears to be fine. `/dev/sda` looks to be a 3TB volume or disk. `/dev/sdb` could be a USB device, a CD/DVD drive or just a failing standalone disk.

That's what you should investigate.

Answer (score 0):

use "smartctl --all /dev/sdb" and chances are you'll find a load of warning messages.

if the drive is failing, ensure you have a backup and a new drive purchased ready.

it could be the controller on the motherboard, or even the sata cable, but chances are it's the drive